# Вопрос по Яндекс Картам

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите пожалуйста, как для этих двух поисковых строк сделать собственные `input`?
То есть, если я ввожу в своей строке город, то поиск по карте происходит так же как и через форму, что на карте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В песочнице Яндекса есть пример поисковой строки-саджеста, результат поиска которой открывается на карте. Думаю это то, что вы ищете:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на яндексе, там есть конструктор форм для карты.

Comment: искал я такое так и не нашел

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]